# select distinct name and combine an objects property in a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, highcharts

I have have a List below, and I am trying to combine the T.name property and sum up the T.score property

Data

```
Name | score
-------------
Jon  | 50
Jon  | 100
Ash  | 100
Ash  | 75
```

Desired result is

```
Jon  | 150
Ash  | 175
```

I am able to do this in LINQ and create a var with the desired results

```
List<PieSeriesData> PiSeriesData = new List<PieSeriesData>();
var x = PiSeriesData.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                    .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(i => i.Score) })
                    .ToList();
```

The issue with that is I need x to be a List type, which is what the HighCharts nuget requires.

Comment: `x` is a list... a generic list of an anonymous type with 2 properties (Id, Total).. Please better explain the problem because it is currently unclear

Comment: If you're calling `.ToList()` then `x` should be a `List<T>`. Is it not?

Comment: The PieSeriesData has more than 2 properties, and x is just a list of 2 properties ID and name currently if i am understanding correctly

Comment: then instead of creating an anonymous object creates a `PieSeriesData` object.

Comment: yes because you are creating in the select an anonymous type with only 2 properties. What is the output type you want?

Comment: In debug mode when I hover over PiSeriesData... which is my List<PieSeriesData> I see a list of PieSeriesData types, when i hover over x in the results view of visual studios ill just see [0] = { Id = "Jon", Total = 780.0 }

Comment: I want another List<PieSeriesData> with the desired result above

Comment: @jon.nicholssoftware.com - yes because it is of a different type.. The first is a list of `PieSeriesData` while the other is of a type that has only 2 properties

Comment: @jon.nicholssoftware.com - can you show the `PieSeriesData` class?

Comment: public class PieSeriesData : BaseObject
    {
        public PieSeriesData();

        public string Color { get; set; }
        public object DataLabels { get; set; }
        public string Drilldown { get; set; }
        public PieSeriesDataEvents Events { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public double? LegendIndex { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool? Selected { get; set; }
        public bool? Sliced { get; set; }
        public double? Y { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126739/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-jon-nicholssoftware-com).

Comment: @jon.nicholssoftware.com - But that object does not have a property of Total.. Where to you want to store the total of the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from the chat you need the output to be a `List<PieSeriesData>`. You need to project a new object of `PieSeriesData` class in the `select` and not of an anonymous type: _See that you also need to assign the properties that exist and not use new ones like `Id` and `Total`:

```
List<PieSeriesData> PiSeriesData = new List<PieSeriesData>();
var x = PiSeriesData.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                    .Select(g => new PieSeriesData { 
                        Name = g.Key, 
                        Score = g.Sum(i => i.Score) 
                    }).ToList();

// Now x is of type: List<PieSeriesData>
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to me 1 on 1 Gilad, This was exactly what I needed x now eqautes to a List<PieSeriesData> type

Comment: @jon.nicholssoftware.com - you are welcome :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Why not create new class

```
public class PieSeriesRenderData
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

And after that return this:

```
List<PieSeriesData> piSeriesData = new List<PieSeriesData>();
var x = piSeriesData.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                    .Select(g => new PieSeriesRenderData { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(i => i.Score) })
                    .ToList();
```

Now you will have object of `List<PieSeriesRenderData>` which you can return it as Json from your web service and you will render the highchart in your ajax.successful method.